# My Odoo application was not responding to my record rule

Tags: python, odoo, acl, record-rules

I have a odoo application in there I created a new group named as officer and provided read only access to the class hr.employee through acl and then I wrote a record rule that

```
<field name="domain_force">[('user_id','!=',user.id)]</field>
<field eval="0" name="perm_unlink"/>
<field eval="0" name="perm_write"/>
<field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
<field eval="0" name="perm_create"/>


<field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
<field eval="0" name="perm_unlink"/>
<field eval="1" name="perm_write"/>
<field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
<field eval="0" name="perm_create"/>
```

to make the user record alone should bee editable, but still all records are in the hr.employee class editable. I don't know to how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In your example you are giving only write permision

```
<field eval="1" name="perm_write"/>
```

To give only read permission use

```
<field eval="0" name="perm_unlink"/>
<field eval="0" name="perm_write"/>
<field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
<field eval="0" name="perm_create"/>
# source addons/document/security/document_security.xml
```

After creating group, then you must check them in `settings -> groups`
to make sure your restrictions are applied correctly and if they are applied correctly and you still didn't get your desired result you must check for other groups too, maybe another group is allowing/restricting user.

Good luck

Comment: hii Dachi sorry i have displayed wrong code here i will change it now

Comment: Then check for another groups, maybe your is blocking some accesses but in the same time another group is allowing them. I had that kind of problem in the past